# How to change windows mobile homescreen programmatically

Tags: windows-mobile, homescreen

Does anyone know if it is possible to change homescreen.

I have a setup that installs all necessary xml files and Homescreen plugins, but I don’t know how to change Homescreen to mine during installation (and remove it during uninstallation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For smartphone devices you can use provisioning xml. If you include the provisioning xml in your cab file as "post-xml" then uninstallation should be handled automatically. Alternatively you could process the provisioning xml yourself using the DMProcessConfigXML API inside a custom setup dll. Check out the following MSDN links for more details.

[Home screen provisioning xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa456136.aspx)
[prexml and /postxml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa457875.aspx)
[DMProcessConfigXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms852998.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any method provided by Microsoft to do what you want.

You can install the SP HomeScreen plugin but it's up to the user to select the homescreen plugin themselves.  You could provide a description of how to do this with the installer dll if you like.   The same is true for PPC Today Items as well.